# Wildcard in Express/node.js router

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to "get rid" of the router in node.js.  Currently, what I have is something that looks like this:

```
app.get '/thing1', (req, res) ->
    res.render 'thing1'

app.get '/thing2', (req, res) ->
    res.render 'thing2'
```

Is there a way to collapse these to something like this:

```
app.get '/(*)', (req, res) ->
    res.render '(*)'
```

PS: I'm using coffeescript, but an answer in any language is OK

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
app.get('/:thing', function (req, res) {
  res.render(req.params.thing)
})
```

Comment: Note that using ":thing" will not match a path like "/path/with/slashes".

Answer (score 5):

From http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB :

```
app.get(/^(.*)$/, function(req, res, next){
  res.send(req.params[0]);
});
```

Working gist:  https://gist.github.com/elliotf/5826944